# Doing a "linear regression" with 2d points under a linear transformation

Tags: regression, matrix, multivariate-regression

Let's say I have a list of 2D points $\vec v_i = (x_i,y_i)$ and the list of points after some linear transformation $\vec v_i'= A\vec v + b + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ is some deviation assumed to be small compared to the position. Is there a way to find the "best fit" matrix $A$ and displacement $b$, like there is in normal linear regression?

Example in R:

```
points <- matrix(runif(2000), nrow = 2)
plot.points <- function(p) {
  transpose <- t(p)
  qplot(x = transpose[,1], y = transpose[,2]) + xlim(c(-5,5)) + ylim(c(-5,5))
}

set.seed(34)
A = matrix(runif(4, -1, 1), ncol = 2)

           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.1104629  0.7697880
[2,]  0.9970808 -0.5231481

## b is just (2,2)
b = matrix(rep(2, 2000), nrow =2)

library(ggplot2)
plot.points(points)
plot.points(A%*%points + b)

## is there a way to reverse engineer A and b 
## assuming we have points and A%*%points + b?
```

Comment: Is it possible the components of the deviation could be correlated?  If not, you have two separate linear regression problems, one for each component of $v$.  If so, you need an honest-to-goodness bivariate regression solution.

Comment: I was thinking about doing something like that, but the problem is specified a little differently than standard linear regression. In linear regression you have the response variable for each $x$: $y$. In this case I have a set of points, `points` and another set of points `A%*%points + b` but no direct correspondence between any two points in the sets. This makes it hard to do least squares because, what is the error for a given $\vec v$? The average distance to each $\vec v'$? I wasn't sure if the math for that holds up the same as in standard linear regression.

Comment: If there is no direct correspondence then there is little you can do, just as you can say almost nothing about the slope when given two sets of one-dimensional points.  But your question as asked strongly implies there *is* such a correspondence: any reader could be forgiven for supposing the two lists give the corresponding points in order.

Comment: Perhaps my question is ill-posed then, but I think the equivalent question in one dimension would be: given two sets of numbers $x$ and $y$, find $a$ and $b$ such that $ax + b$ "fits" $y$ as best as possible, where I can't think of a good measurement of "fits" and perhaps that is why my question is ill posed. The measure of "fit" could potentially be the sum of the squared errors between all of the points $\sum_{ij} (x_i - y_j)^2$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps I will post a second question with the 1d version of this problem @whuber

Answer (score 2):

A simple way that avoids having to solve equations or invert matrices is by defining the linearly independent functions $f_1(x,y) = 1$, $f_2(x,y) = x$, and $f_3(x,y) = y$ and then using Gram-Schmidt to create an orthogonal basis for the 3-dimensional vector space spanned by the 3 functions. If we take the first basis vector $e_1(x,y)$ to be $f_1(x,y) = 1$, then the next one $e_2(x,y)$ becomes:

$$e_2(x,y) = f_2(x,y) - \frac{\left\langle f_2,e_1\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_1,e_1\right\rangle}e_1(x,y) = x - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i = x - \left\langle x\right\rangle$$

The third basis vector is:

$$\begin{split}
e_3(x,y) &= f_3(x,y) - \frac{\left\langle f_3,e_1\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_1,e_1\right\rangle}e_1(x,y) - \frac{\left\langle f_3,e_2\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_2,e_2\right\rangle}e_2(x,y)\\ &= y - \left\langle y\right\rangle - \frac{\left\langle xy\right\rangle - \left\langle x\right\rangle \left\langle y\right\rangle }{\left\langle x^2\right\rangle - \left\langle x\right\rangle^2}\left(x - \left\langle x\right\rangle\right)
\end{split}
$$

The best fit to the data is given by the projection on the 3-dimensional linear space of each of the two components of $\vec{v}' = (q_1,q_2)$. If the errors were exactly zero, we would have:

$$q_1(x,y) = \frac{\left\langle q_1,e_1\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_1,e_1\right\rangle}e_1(x,y) + \frac{\left\langle q_1,e_2\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_2,e_2\right\rangle}e_2(x,y) +\frac{\left\langle q_1,e_3\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_3,e_3\right\rangle}e_3(x,y)  $$

and

$$q_2(x,y) = \frac{\left\langle q_2,e_1\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_1,e_1\right\rangle}e_1(x,y) + \frac{\left\langle q_2,e_2\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_2,e_2\right\rangle}e_2(x,y) +\frac{\left\langle q_2,e_3\right\rangle}{\left\langle e_3,e_3\right\rangle}e_3(x,y)$$

in case of random errors this yields the least squarest fit. The inner products are readily expressed in terms of averages of the measured quantities, so, all the coefficients are easily obtained.