# Best fitting linear transformation (not quite regression)

Tags: least-squares

This is related to a previous question:

[Doing a "linear regression" with 2d points under a linear transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222700/doing-a-linear-regression-with-2d-points-under-a-linear-transformation?noredirect=1#comment421542_222700)

Actually it is the 1D version of that question.

This problem is similar to linear regression, but not quite the same. Say I have two sets of real numbers $X$ and $Y$, with sizes $m$ and $n$, respectively, and in general, $m \neq n$. Suppose I have the hypothesis that for each $y_j \in Y$,
$$ y_j = ax_i + b + \epsilon_j$$ 
for 2 real numbers $a$ and $b$ and some $x_i \in X$. Is there a way I can find $a$ and $b$ so that it minimizes the total error:
$$\sum_{x\in X,y \in Y} (x - y)^2 \text{ ?}$$

Example in R:

```
a <- 4
b <- -2
x <- runif(100)
y <- sample(a*x, 200, replace = TRUE) + b + rnorm(200, mean = 0, sd = .03)
## recover a and b?
```

Since linear transformations preserve ordering, I figured I could just sort $x$ and $y$, get a correspondance and do a linear regression. However, $x$ and $y$ are different lengths here. So basically what I could do is repeat or resample $x$ until it is the same length as $y$, *then* sort and do a linear regression. i.e.

```
x.lm <- sample(x, length(y), replace = TRUE)
lm.ab <- lm(sort(y) ~ sort(x.lm))
summary(lm.ab)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   sort(x.lm)  
    -1.8574       3.6682  

qplot(x = sort(x.lm), y = sort(y)) + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Get decent results but not as good as I'd like. Repeating $x$ works better, but I don't think it's quite as general:

```
lm(sort(y) ~ sort(rep(x, times = 2)))

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  sort(rep(x, times = 2))  
            -1.9626                   3.8532
```

Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is your sum over all pairs, $x_i,y_j$ or did you mean something else there?

Comment: Do you mean $y_j = ax_i + b + \epsilon_{ij}$? there will be a different error term for every $i$, $j$ pair. And by total error, do you mean $\sum_{ij} \epsilon_{ij}^2$? What are your choice variables? Just $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You'd have to search over possible assignments of x values to y values, which is a discrete optimization problem. You'd then have parameters a and b, plus one assignment parameter for each y value. Given the presence of noise, allowing assignment of any x value to any y value would make bad overfitting possible. I think obtaining a good solution would require further constraints.

Comment: I  think I can describe my question as looking for the *least squares affine transformation* when I don't know the correspondence between points.

Comment: See here: http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~mchung/teaching/768/reading/lecture06-affine.pdf